# how to retrieve the data from the database using pyodbc and sql server with python

Tags: python, select, pyodbc, streamlit

I have a python code that connect with sql server and retrieve the required data based on select query and display the result as a table with columns and rows.

The problem is that the retrieved data is displayed without **columns name** as shown in the picture below.

[image]

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

st_input_update = st.number_input if is_numeric_dtype(all_columns) else st.text_input
search_term=st_input_update("Enter Search Term")
                        
sql='select * from testDB.dbo.t1 where last LIKE  ? '
param=f'%{search_term}%'
rows = cursor.execute(sql, param).fetchall() 
st.dataframe(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `st.dataframe` You need to create a `pandas` `Dataframe`.
What you get after your query is not a `DataFrame`, it is a `list` of `tuples`.

Try this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ["ID", "first_name", "last_name"])  

st.dataframe(df)
```

Comment: i tried your answer it display the below error:
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 1), indices imply (6, 3)`

Comment: i fix it by adding this function to the dataframe `.from_records()`

Comment: Ah ok. Your code implies that it would be (6,3). You should post your `.from_records()` as it's own answer to this post.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding this function to the dataframe `.from_records()`
so the line of code becomes:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns =columns)
```